# Need help fixing my Conway Game of Life code

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am making a Conway Game of Life that it starts with a predefined board,  I made that board through an two dimensional Array, have implemented the rules and they seem to be working, the problem is that the different generations just appear next to previous one without replacing it (see image [1])

image:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

So, what i needed is to make the following generations replace the previous ones on the HTML display.

```
var gfg=new Array(10);

for (var COL=0; COL<gfg.length;COL++){
    gfg[COL]=new Array(10);   
}

run();

function run(){  
    board1();
    rules();    
}

function rules(){
        for (var i=0; i<10;i++){
            for(var j=0; j<10; j++){
                const cell = gfg[i][j];
                let numNeighbours = 0;
                for (let x = -1; x < 2; x++) {
                    for (let y = -1; y < 2; y++) {
                        if (x === 0 && y === 0) {
                            continue;
                        }
                    var x_cell = i + x;
                    var y_cell = j + y;

                 if (x_cell > 0 && y_cell > 0 && x_cell <0 && y_cell <0) {
                            const currentNeighbour = 1;
                            numNeighbours=numNeighbours+currentNeighbour;
                        }
                    }                  
                }
                if (cell === 1 && numNeighbours < 2) {
                    gfg[i][j] = 0;
                } else if (cell === 1 && numNeighbours > 3) {
                    gfg[i][j] = 0;
                } else if (cell === 0 && numNeighbours === 3) {
                    gfg[i][j] = 1;
                }                         
            } 
        draw();

       }
    } 

function draw(){          
        for (var i=0; i<10;i++){
            for(var j=0; j<10; j++){                                
                //Writes in HTML according to the coordinate value
                if(gfg[i][j]===0){
                    document.write("&#9723;");
                }else if(gfg[i][j]===1){
                    document.write("&#9724;");
                }                              
            }
        document.write("<br>");      
        }

}
//predefined board
function board1() {
    gfg[0][0] = 1;
    gfg[0][1] = 0;
    gfg[0][2] = 1;
    gfg[0][3] = 0;
    gfg[0][4] = 0;
    gfg[0][5] = 1;
    gfg[0][6] = 0;
    gfg[0][7] = 0;
    gfg[0][8] = 0;
    gfg[0][9] = 1;
    gfg[1][0] = 0;
    gfg[1][1] = 0;
    gfg[1][2] = 0;
    gfg[1][3] = 0;
    gfg[1][4] = 0;
    gfg[1][5] = 0;
    gfg[1][6] = 0;
    gfg[1][7] = 1;
    gfg[1][8] = 0;
    gfg[1][9] = 0;
    gfg[2][0] = 0;
    gfg[2][1] = 0;
    gfg[2][2] = 0;
    gfg[2][3] = 1;
    gfg[2][4] = 0;
    gfg[2][5] = 1;
    gfg[2][6] = 1;
    gfg[2][7] = 0;
    gfg[2][8] = 0;
    gfg[2][9] = 0;
    gfg[3][0] = 0;
    gfg[3][1] = 0;
    gfg[3][2] = 1;
    gfg[3][3] = 0;
    gfg[3][4] = 1;
    gfg[3][5] = 0;
    gfg[3][6] = 0;
    gfg[3][7] = 0;
    gfg[3][8] = 0;
    gfg[3][9] = 1;
    gfg[4][0] = 0;
    gfg[4][1] = 0;
    gfg[4][2] = 0;
    gfg[4][3] = 0;
    gfg[4][4] = 1;
    gfg[4][5] = 0;
    gfg[4][6] = 0;
    gfg[4][7] = 0;
    gfg[4][8] = 0;
    gfg[4][9] = 0;
    gfg[5][0] = 0;
    gfg[5][1] = 1;
    gfg[5][2] = 0;
    gfg[5][3] = 0;
    gfg[5][4] = 0;
    gfg[5][5] = 0;
    gfg[5][6] = 0;
    gfg[5][7] = 0;
    gfg[5][8] = 0;
    gfg[5][9] = 0;
    gfg[6][0] = 0;
    gfg[6][1] = 0;
    gfg[6][2] = 0;
    gfg[6][3] = 0;
    gfg[6][4] = 1;
    gfg[6][5] = 0;
    gfg[6][6] = 1;
    gfg[6][7] = 0;
    gfg[6][8] = 1;
    gfg[6][9] = 0;
    gfg[7][0] = 1;
    gfg[7][1] = 0;
    gfg[7][2] = 0;
    gfg[7][3] = 1;
    gfg[7][4] = 0;
    gfg[7][5] = 0;
    gfg[7][6] = 0;
    gfg[7][7] = 1;
    gfg[7][8] = 0;
    gfg[7][9] = 0;
    gfg[8][0] = 0;
    gfg[8][1] = 0;
    gfg[8][2] = 1;
    gfg[8][3] = 0;
    gfg[8][4] = 1;
    gfg[8][5] = 0;
    gfg[8][6] = 0;
    gfg[8][7] = 0;
    gfg[8][8] = 0;
    gfg[8][9] = 0;
    gfg[9][0] = 0;
    gfg[9][1] = 1;
    gfg[9][2] = 0;
    gfg[9][3] = 0;
    gfg[9][4] = 0;
    gfg[9][5] = 0;
    gfg[9][6] = 0;
    gfg[9][7] = 0;
    gfg[9][8] = 1;
    gfg[9][9] = 0;

}



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKrFj.png
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write` it's not good practice. And to quickly fix your code, you can use `document.body.innerHTML = '';` before you star drawing to clear what was in prev generation, if you don't have any other html in document. You will also need delay between generations use setTimeout, setInterval or requestAnimationFrame

Comment: Your `draw()` function simply appends HTML to the document.  If you want to have a board and update that board, add a `<div>` and replace the `innerHTML` of that div.

Comment: (upvoted because @LeonelAmaral14 included all of his code and a clear description of his problem.  The fact that he is apparently new to JavaScript/HTML doesn't mean he should get downvoted without comment...)

Comment: @JayBuckman Sorry guys, i tried the document.body.innerHTML instead of document.write, but nothing shows in html now... Can you guys edit my code please so i can understand better? im really noob at this....

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>       
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="cells" id="tabuleiro">
            <script src="custom.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*this is if you are using `document.write()`*
All you will have to do is clear the container of the previous write with `document.body.innerHTML = "";` this will clear your previous writes and then you can go through the loop again.

If you need to use html and javascript only canvas will still work as it is a built in html tag. However if you still wish to proceed with using html to display your cells then create a new `div` tag and give it an id e.g: `id="life_container"` then grab a reference to this tag when the page finishes loading and on every frame empty the div then go through your loop and fill it with your elements.

```
var container;
document.onload = function() {
   container = document.getElementById('life_container');
}

// clear container
container.innerHtml = "";

// fill container
container.innerHtml += gfg[i][j] === 0 ? "&#9723;" : "&#9724;";
```

However I might suggest some improvements by using canvas instead of html to display your game of life. You can use [P5 library](https://p5js.org/), to run your loop and display it. You will need to add in extra calculation to figure out "where" to draw your cell on canvas but not much more.

Comment: Sorry guys, i tried the document.body.innerHTML instead of document.write, but nothing shows in html now... Can you guys please edit my code so i can understand better? im really noob at this....

Comment: I shlould only use HTML and pure Javascript

Comment: @LeonelAmaral14 Updated my answer please give that a try. also side note you may want to slow your loop down as well. maybe something like 50 milliseconds.

Comment: That .innerHtml doesnt seem to work beause it replaces the values displayed at each for cycle, each time the for cycle reads the array it replaces with the most recent value read and at the end only displays the last value in the loop, the document.write in the other hand adds a new value to the html display at each cycle instead of replacing the previous and at the end of the "for" loop i have all the elements of my array.  What i think i need is a array that saves the previous generations coordinates so i can (.innerHtml = " ";) and then load that array and apply the rules and so on...

Comment: you can generate a string of html the same way i'm showing in the block of code instead of `innerHtml += '&#9723;'` make a `let text = "<empty string>"` and then replace the `innerHtml` with `text += '&#9723;'` and then at the end of the double for loop do `container.innerHtml = text;`

Comment: i had to remake my game and go on a diferent aproach, but thank you for your time man :)@nicholas labrecque

Comment: not a problem I figured you would end up remaking it a different way. Did you go with canvas I presume?